# Swift - запись массива в базу данных Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Пытаюсь записать массив в базу данных, но он не записывается (остается пустым).

Код:

```
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        save()
        
        render()
        
    }
    
        
    func save(){
        let joe = Person()
        joe.trackPoint = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
        print("Array write")
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.add(joe)
        try! realm.commitWrite()
    }

    func render(){
        let people = realm.objects(Person.self)
        for person in people{
            print(person.trackPoint)
            print("Read ok")
        }
    }


}

class Person: Object{
    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName: String = ""
    var trackPoint: [String] = []
}
```

Вывод консоли:

```
Array write
[]
Read ok
[]
Read ok
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В realm по другому записываются массивы:

```
var trackPoint = List<String>()
```

и, соответственно, добавляются:

```
joe.trackPoint.append("aaa")
```

Документация: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet

Comment: т.е. так надо пройтись по всем элементам массива? А сразу весь массив нельзя записать в пустую ячейку?

Comment: Да, пройдитесь по элементам массива в цикле for и добавьте каждый из них через append.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, вы мне очень помогли. Но оказывается, что циклом for перебирать ничего не нужно, можно сделать так:

joe.trackPoint.append(objectsIn: myArray)

и тогда запишется весь массив сразу. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Отлично) Отметьте тогда ответ, что он отвечен, чтобы закрыть его.